# Calculate limit without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to calculate this limit whitout using L'Hopital's rule or Taylor polynomials:

$$\lim_{ x\to \pi/4 } \frac{1 - \tan(x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

I know how to make it using L'Hopital and that the result is $-2$ ,but I'm getting nowhere when I try without it. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $t=x-\frac{\pi}{4}$, then
$$\frac{1-\tan x}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1-\tan\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{t}=\frac{1}{t}\cdot\left(1-\frac{\tan t+\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}{1-\tan \frac{\pi}{4}\tan t}\right)=\frac{1}{t}\left(1-\frac{\tan t+1}{1-\tan t}\right)=\frac{-2\tan t}{t(1-\tan t)}$$
Now, take the limit as $t\to 0$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\tan x}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-2\tan t}{t(1-\tan t)}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-2\tan t\cos t}{t(1-\tan t)\cos t}\\
&=-2\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t(\cos t-\sin t)}\\
&=-2\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos t-\sin t}\right)\\
&=-2(1)(1)\\
&=\color{blue}{-2}
\end{align}

Comment: While all the answers are valid and helped me,I chose this because it doesn't imply the use of more advanced concepts like derivatives.Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Hint: What is the definition of the derivative of $\tan(x)$ at $x=\pi/4$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})}$
But what's the point? I can't use L'Hopital's rule because the exercise ask it, not because I don't how to use it.I don't understand how can I use the derivative of $\tan(x)$ at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in this exercise.

Comment: @DerRosenkavalier By definition: $$\tan'(\pi/4)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \pi/4}\frac{\tan(x)-1}{x-\pi/4}$$. How does this compare to your limit?

Comment: L'Hopital isn't being used here; just the definition of the derivative. It's important to know the difference.

Comment: @zhw I agree with your comment. This type of question sometimes rasises debate as to "allowed ways forward.  For example, is the use of asymptotic analysis permitted here?  IMHO, yes absolutely.  Yet others would argue that that approach is tantamount to the use of LHR.  ;-)

Comment: @DerRosenkavalier : My answer posted here explicitly explains how you can use the value of the derivative of $\tan x$ at $\pi/4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Reveillark Oh, I see.I misunderstood you. I thought that you believed that I didn't know how to calculate the derivative of $ \tan(x) $ to use L' Hopital's rule.
I chose Mario G answer because it doesn't imply the use of concepts more advanced like derivatives,which I'm not sure if all professors would approve in an exercise of this kind in an exam,but this still solves the problem.
Thanks for your answer! I can't upvote it because I don't have the minimum reputation points.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}.
$$
Apply it to the case where $f(x) = \tan x$ and $a=\pi/4$.  Then $f(a) = 1$ and $f'(a) = \sec^2 a = \sec^2(\pi/4) = 2$.  Therefore
$$
2 = \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\tan x - \tan(\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}.
$$

So $-2$ is the answer to the question as you've posed it.

Answer (score 3):

We have the identities

$$\begin{align}\frac{1-\tan x}{x-\pi/4}&=-\frac{\tan(x-\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}(1+\tan x)\\\\
&=-\frac{\sin(x-\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}\frac{1+\tan x}{\cos(x-\pi/4)}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes,I could use that $\lim_{ x\to 0 }\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1 $ . Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.  This is a very efficient approach that circumvents use of L'Hospital's Rule, as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following hint. Try to write $\tan(x)$ in terms of $\sin(x) $ and $\cos(x)$. A little bit of rearranging and then use the following,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

A little bit of work yields the result.